# jQuery Validate Custom Rule Ignore a Checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

With some help from other post the related to validating multiple checkboxes, I decided to go with this customer rul

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkBox", function(value, element) {
    return $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0;
}, "");
```

I then call this in the rules section:

```
field_name:{checkBox:true}
```

This works great for making sure at least one checkbox is checked in the field, which is really all I need. However, when I started to test I realized I have a checkbox that is set to show/hide a div.  This checkbox is being factored into the validation and in return is making the submitted data not valid.

I have tried using `ignore:".class_name"` but have been unsuccessful in getting the script to actually ignore this field.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction in getting a checkbox to be ignored in the custom validation?  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the "return" line to

```
return $("input[type=checkbox]:checked:not(.class_name)").length > 0;
```

Comment: Sometimes the most simple things can be overlooked.  That worked beautifully, thanks for the response!